# how to understand the linkagemex function inside of the defaule linkage function in matlab

Tags: matlab, mex

I need to rewrite the linkage function in matlab. Now, as I examine it, I realized there is a method called linkagemex inside of it. But I simply cannot step into this method to see its code. Can anyone help me out with this strange situastion?

```
function Z= linkage (Y, method, pdistArg, varargin)

         Z=linkagemex(Y,method);
```

PS. I think I am pretty good at learning, but matlab is not so easy to learn. If you have good references to learn it well, feel free to let me know. Thanks very much for your time and attention.

Comment: @Sam Roberts, do you happen to know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @m.s. mentions, you've found a call to a MEX function. MEX functions are implemented as C code that is compiled into a function callable by MATLAB.

As you've found, you can't step into this method (as it is compiled C code, not MATLAB code), and you don't have access to the C source code, as it's not supplied with MATLAB.

Normally, you would be at kind of a dead end here. Fortunately, that's not quite the case with `linkagemex`. You'll notice on line 240 of `linkage.m` that it actually does a test to see whether `linkagemex` is present. If it isn't, it instead calls a local subfunction `linkageold`.

I think you can assume that `linkageold` does at least roughly the same thing as `linkagemex`. You may like to test them out with a few suitable input arguments to see if they give the same results. If so, then you should be able to rewrite `linkage` using the code from `linkageold` rather than `linkagemex`.

---

I'm going to comment more generally, related to your PS. Over the last few days I've been answering a few of your questions - and you do seem like a fast learner. But it's not really that MATLAB is hard to learn - you should realize that what you're attempting (rewriting the clustering behaviour of `phytree`) is not an easy thing to do for even a very advanced user.

MathWorks write their stuff in a way that makes it (hopefully) easy to use - but not necessarily in a way that makes it easy for users to extend or modify. Sometimes they do things for performance reasons that make it impossible for you to modify, as you've found with `linkagemex`. In addition, `phytree` is implemented using an old style of OO programming that is no longer properly documented, so even if you have the code, it's difficult to work out what it even does, unless you happen to have been working with MATLAB for years and remember how the old style worked.

My advice would be that you might find it easier to just implement your own clustering method from scratch, rather than trying to build on top of `phytree`. There will be a lot of further headaches for you down the road you're on, and mostly what you'll learn is that `phytree` is implemented in an obscure old-fashioned way. If you take the opportunity to implement your own from scratch, you could instead be learning how to implement things using more modern OO methods, which would be more useful for you in the future.

Your call though, that's just my thoughts. Happy to continue trying to answer questions when I can, if you choose to continue with the `phytree` route.

Comment: The main thing with implementing my own clustering method is that I am not very familiar with the pseucode for the default method. May be it does not matter too much, as long as the general IDEA is correct (I am not so sure). So to be on the safe side, it's better if I get myself familiar with it first. Thanks again, sam.

Answer (score 0):

You came across a MEX function, which "are dynamically linked subroutines that the MATLAB interpreter loads and executes". Since these subroutines are natively compiled, you cannot step into them. See also the MATLAB documentation about [MEX functions](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/introducing-mex-files.html).